# Spring cache mongodb with Reactive mongo autoconfigure

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-cache, reactive-mongo-java

I am trying to use [spring-cache-mongodb](https://github.com/arhs/spring-cache-mongodb) as a cache in my reactive spring application. The problem are the 2 depenndencies

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive', version: '2.4.3'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '2.4.3'
```

1. `ReactiveMongoTemplate` is required by application reactive repositories by default.
2. `MongoTemplate` is used by the `spring-cache-mongodb`

But they cannot be used together, any suggestions for how to use `spring-cache-mongodb` with reactive Mongo data.

Comment: This probably means the framework/ library `spring-cache-mongodb` may not be supporting the reactive paradigm as of now